# typing module - String Literal Type

Tags: python, python-3.5, typing

I'm using the new Python 3.5 module [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) and it has been joyous.

I was wondering how one might specify a type based on an exact string literal. For example, a function is guaranteed to return one of the four strings - "North", "West", "East", "South - how can we express that as a specific type variable, instead of just `str`.

I looked through the documentation, finding the `Union` type and the `TypeVar` function, but was unable to find an answer.

An example function expressing this problem:

```
def compute_quadrant(x: int, y: int) -> str:
    if x > 0 and y > 0:
        return 'I'
    elif x < 0 and y > 0:
        return 'II'
    elif x < 0 and y < 0:
        return 'III'
    elif x > 0 and y < 0:
        return 'IV'
```

Instead of just returning `str`, I'd like to to return a more specific type that is one of four values - `"I"`, `"II"`, `"III"`, or `"IV"`.

In Typescript, one can do: `type Quadrant = "I" | "II" | "III" | "IV"` - is there any nice Python sugar for this use case with the `typing` module?

Comment: FWIW, there is a [discussion](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3062) about adding types that represent just a few specific values. But certainly, there's no need for that in this case, since `enum` fits perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Disregarding the `typing` module you asked about, one solution to your problem could be the use of an `Enum` as supposed in multiple comments. The code for this would look like this:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Quadrant(Enum):
    I = 1
    II = 2
    III = 3
    IV = 4

def compute_quadrant(x: int, y: int) -> Quadrant:
    if x > 0 and y > 0:
        return Quadrant.I
    elif x < 0 and y > 0:
        return Quadrant.II
    elif x < 0 and y < 0:
        return Quadrant.III
    elif x > 0 and y < 0:
        return Quadrant.IV
    # return None  # this is what happens without an else clause!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    quad = compute_quadrant(1, -1)
    print(quad, type(quad))              # -> Quadrant.IV <enum 'Quadrant'>
    print(quad.name, type(quad.name))    # -> IV <class 'str'>
    print(quad.value, type(quad.value))  # -> 4 <class 'int'>
```

As you can see you can use the Enums name and value. The name is one of the strings you asked for.

One issue I see here is the missing else clause in the function and mypy's current behaviour of accepting `None` as a valid return value for `Quadrant`. This should be handled manually.